# Counting commas in a sentence with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'll preface this by saying I am a newbie at XQuery. That being said, I work on a project that uses XML to structure texts. So my document looks something like this :

```
<text>
 <paragraph>
   <sentence id="1"> This, is a sentence.</sentence>
   <sentence id="2"> This, is, a sentence.</sentence>
   <sentence id="3"> This, is, a, sentence.</sentence>
   <sentence id="4"> This is a sentence.</sentence>
 </paragraph>
</text>
```

I need to count the number of commas per sentence for a downstream linguistic analysis. I tried doing this :

```
let $comma := "&#44;"

for $arg in doc("document.xml")/text/paragraph/sentence

return count($arg//$comma)
```

I'm using Oxygen 14.0 and the XQuery editor is not giving me any syntax error messages. When I run it, I get a result, but one that is obviously false :

```
2 2 2 2
```

I modified the return line to this (since I don't understand the difference between // and / and wanted to try something) :

```
return count ($arg/$comma)
```

And now the result is :

```
1 1 1 1
```

Obviously, both of the results are false. There are many different sentences, with varying numbers of commas. I don't understand why it's giving those results. Please help?

Comment: `$arg/$comma` means "for every item in the sequence $arg, evaluate the expression `$comma` once, and return a sequence with the concatenated results". There is one item in $arg, so the expression returns one instance of $comma. So `count($arg/$comma)` is 1. By contrast, `$arg//$comma` means "for each descendant-or-self node of $arg, evaluate $comma once". A sentence element has two descendant-or-self nodes, the sentence element and its contained text node, so `count($arg//$comma)` is 2. All very logical.`

Answer (score 2):

Appending a string to a location path does not execute a substring search for that string. However, [functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) can be used in XPath expressions to process strings.

One way to solve this is to use a comma as a delimiter param in `fn:tokenize`, and return one less that the number of tokens:

```
for $arg in doc("document.xml")/text/paragraph/sentence
return (count(tokenize($arg, ',')) - 1)
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but the first paragraph is quite wrong. In fact your solution is a valid XPath 2.0 expression.

Comment: @MichaelKay Maybe I tried too hard to simplify the explanation and made it confusing. I know the solution is valid XPath 2. I updated the answer with a more precise explanation.